# AndroidDriver "NoClassDefFound" errors occur during Runtime but not on Compile time

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I run tests, I get the following error, "NoClassDefFound" AndroidDriver.

There are no errors during Compile time but happens only on Runtime. (I included the jar file selenium-server-standalone.jar in the build path)

If I include the jar file externally, then "NoClassDefFound" is the outcome; and if I include the jar inside libs folder then the entire test stuck during execution (tried with more than 4 pcs).

Please help me on this!!!!

Comment: did you try to clean your project ?

Comment: Yes, I clean my project everytime I add jar and whenever I make changes on it. If you need my project, I can forward it to you for review. Thank you!

Comment: Whenever **"selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar"** is placed under **"libs"** folder, I get the following error:
Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (bsh.util.AWTConsole$1) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this..

Comment: Is this a maven project? What do you mean by adding jar to libs folder? What do you mean by adding the jar file externally? In my experience, NoClassDefFound errors happen always at run time.

Comment: I am not using maven. Adding jars away from project's "libs" folder is what I call externally. Once you externally add the jar, "Selenium-server-standalone.2.xx.x.jar" you can find the project as error free state. On running the project you will see the error "NoClassDefFoundError".

Comment: When I place the jar under "libs" folder and run them, It eventually stuck/hang with the above error "DX warning" then "Heap space issue". I tried/increased all the combinations to make it run by editing **eclipse.ini**; still facing issue.